# Put JTextField text into JList

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jlist, gettext

So the problem I'm having at the moment is that I need to put text from a JTextField into a JList whenever I clicked a JButton. But how do I do this?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` shows you how to dynamically update the ListModel with text from a text field when a button is clicked. It also shows you how to remove an item from the ListModel.